# Replacing missing values with random in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, missing-data

I have a 2D numpy array with binary data, i.e. 0s and 1s (not observed or observed). For some instances, that information is missing (NaN). Since the missing values are random in the data set, I think the best way to replace them would be using random 0s and 1s.

Here is some example code:

```
import numpy as np
row, col = 10, 5
matrix = np.random.randint(2, size=(row,col))
matrix = matrix.astype(float)
matrix[1,2] = np.nan
matrix[5,3] = np.nan
matrix[8,0] = np.nan
matrix[np.isnan(matrix)] = np.random.randint(2)
```

The problem with this is that all NaNs are replaced with the same value, either 0 or 1, while I would like both. Is there a simpler solution than for example a for loop calling each NaN separately? The data set I'm working on is a lot bigger than this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
nan_mask = np.isnan(matrix)
matrix[nan_mask] = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=np.count_nonzero(nan_mask))
```

Comment: I think it should be `np.random.randint(0, **2**, size=np.count_nonzero(nan_mask))`, shouldn't it? Otherwise I seem to get only 0s. Great idea, by the way! I should have thought of this myself, since I was already using `np.random.randit()` with a size specification...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a vectorized function:

```
random_replace = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.random.randint(2) if np.isnan(x) else x)
random_replace(matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks! I never really got the hang of vectorised functions, I'm using them way too rarely. This is very clear to understand, though. Nevertheless, I prefer the solution of Mr E.

Comment: @Lilith-Elina No problem, I think theirs is better too.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the missing values are random in the data set, I think the best way to replace them would be using random 0s and 1s.

I'd heartily contradict you here. Unless you have stochastic model that proves that assuming equal probability for each element to be either 0 or 1, that would bias your observation.

Now, I don't know where your data comes from, but "2D array" sure sounds like an image signal, or something of the like. You can find that most of the energy in many signal types is in low frequencies; if something of the like is the case for you, you can probably get lesser distortion by replacing the missing values with an element of a low-pass filtered version of your 2D array.

Either way, since you need to call `numpy.isnan` from python to check whether a value is NaN, I think the only way to solve this is writing an efficient loop, unless you want to senselessly calculate a huge random 2D array just to fill in a few missing numbers.

**EDIT**: oh, I like the vectorized version; it's effectively what I'd call a *efficient loop*, since it does the looping without interpreting a python loop iteration each time.

**EDIT2**: the mask method with counting nonzeros is even more effective, I guess :)

Comment: My data are mutations which are either there or not in different sequencing samples. Since the sequencing wasn't deep enough in some samples at some places, values are missing. This seems to be more or less random, so I thought doing a random replacement multiple times and comparing the results would be more elegant than e.g. replacing with 0.5 or imputing means (which works, but doesn't make much sense for binary data, does it?).

Comment: It might, unless you're a quantum physicist, maybe :) no really, I'm happy to hear you have in-depth understanding of your data; typically people just *fix* their data by inventing stuff that might seriously *break* their observation here on SO (because programmers not necessarily are good theoretics), so I think you should be fine with the other answers. Thanks for the nice comment!

Comment: I'm neither a "real" programmer nor a mathematician/statistician/whatever, so I'm still having difficulties with these kinds of things. I just try to think about the problem as logically as possible, and try what seems to make the most sense. ;-) So, thanks for giving me some feedback on my reasoning and not only on the code.

Comment: hehe, thanks for the kind words, you're welcome! You could think of my idea to be like "interpolating" for the missing values (rather than randomizing them).